# C++ std::regex. Error in searching substring by regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Update: actually cuted off all unnecessary code in question.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

I wrote function what search substrings in string by regular expressin and replace it by indexes (i1, i2, i16...). It works well, but after here is no more matching substrings in string, i get error:

> Expression: string iterator not dereferencable

I match this way:

```
std::smatch m;
std::regex rExp("[a-z][a-z0-9]*");
strBuf = "*10.5)*51E-10";
while (std::regex_search (strBuf, m, rExp)) {...
```

In main() it works fine, but as it heppens in function error message pops up.

Full code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <regex>
    #include <fstream>

    std::string IntToString(int a) {
       std::string result;
       int number = abs(a);
       while (number) {
          result += (number % 10) + 48;
          number /= 10;
       }
       if (a < 0) result += '-';
       std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
       return result;
    }

    void searchLexemes(std::string& input, int& i)
    {
            std::string strBuf;
            std::smatch m;
            std::regex rExp("[a-z][a-z0-9]*");
            strBuf = input;
            input = "";
            bool foundAny = false;
            while (std::regex_search (strBuf, m, rExp)) { //here error happens
                    auto x = m.str();
                    input += m.prefix();
                    input += "i" + IntToString(i);
                    strBuf = m.suffix();
                    foundAny = true;
                    i++;
            }
            foundAny ? input += m.suffix() : input = strBuf;
    }

    void main() {
            std::string input;
            input = "fgs1=(b+a*5.01E+10)+a*10+(c*10.5)*51E-10";

            std::ofstream fout;
            fout.open("OUTPUT.TXT");

            int i = 1;

            searchLexemes(input, i);

            std::cout << input << std::endl;
            //expected result - "i1=(i2+i3*i5)+i3*i8+(i4*i7)*i6"

            system ("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? std::regex is only available since  `GCC 4.9.0` and does nothing before that version.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012. std::regex is working.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2012. std::regex is working". Or does it? [This](http://pastebin.com/6xw7CsMJ) (a 12 line program) triggers the non-dereferenceable iterator exception. No place to fail here, yet it fails. I *suspect* std::regex is not working that well in VS2012.

Comment: I'm not sure what is std::smatch but if here is string longer then 1 letter this code is working http://pastebin.com/1B45K2sU

Comment: Looks like m is somehow linked with std.